# Getting elevation heights from folder of thousands of shapefiles that apparently come from LiDAR?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, lidar

I obtained a few folders purporting to come from LiDAR data taken of a U.S. county. The directories are set up like this.

```
Data-folder
- be_rasters
-- 692500_725000
--- dblbnd.adf
--- hdr.adf
--- metadata.xml
--- prj.adf
--- sta.adf
--- w001001.adf
--- w001001x.adf
-- (thousands more folders with this naming convention format and files within them named the same thing)
- contour
-- shp
--- Contour_692500_735000.cpg
--- Contour_692500_735000.dbf
--- Contour_692500_735000.prj
--- Contour_692500_735000.sbn
--- Contour_692500_735000.sbx
--- Contour_692500_735000.shp
--- Contour_692500_735000.shp.xml
--- Contour_692500_735000.shx
--- (Thousands more files with similar naming conventions, with the same extensions)
```

It appears that each shapefile contains data for a small area of the county. I want to obtain the average elevation above/below sea level for each section of the county.

How do I obtain that information from these files?

I have QGIS. I tried opening a few .shp files in it. But trying to open all the .shp files at once freezes the program.

Comment: You seem to be looking at shapefiles and also some Esri Grid Format files.

Comment: the `be_rasters` are very probably "bare earth (be)" DEMs in ESRI GRID format. This is the data you want to use, not the contour shapefiles. Note DO NOT change the folders under the `be_rasters` folder in any way, particularly don't rename or move any of them and don't touch the `info` directory. ESRI GRIDS have a very particular folder format and are very easy to corrupt. If you need to move the data you can move the top level `be_rasters` folder.

Comment: Here is info on of working with ESRI raster GRID files using QGIS.  https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/esri-rasters-in-grass-or-qgis/   and here is a nice description of the file components of the ESRI shapefiles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile  and here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/what-is-a-shapefile.htm.  There are tools for calculating descriptive statistics on raster data here https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/raster_tools/rasterlayerstatistics.html.  Maybe find a local grad student to help run this in batch?

Comment: @GBG I'm trying to open the many `.adf` files in QGIS but am running into trouble. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333383/invalid-data-source-when-trying-to-open-many-w001001-adf-files