# "Invalid Data Source" When trying to open many w001001.adf files

Tags: qgis, esri-grid-format

I have a folder with more than 9,000 subfolders, each with ESRI GRID files. Here's the setup of the directories and subdirectories.

```
Data-folder
- be_rasters
-- 692500_725000
--- dblbnd.adf
--- hdr.adf
--- metadata.xml
--- prj.adf
--- sta.adf
--- w001001.adf
--- w001001x.adf
-- (thousands more folders with this naming convention format and files within them named the same thing)
```

I'm trying to work in QGIS 3.8 to open the 9000+ `w001001.adf` files in the folders in `be_rasters` directory. In QGIS, I go to Layers >> Add Vector Layer, then choose "Directory" as a Source Type and "Arc/Binary Coverage" in the "Source" section. Then under "Vector Dataset(s)" I select `be_rasters`.

But when I click "Add," I get this error.

```
Invalid Data Source: path/to/Data-folder/be_rasters  is not a valid or recognized data source.
```

How do I load all the `w001001.adf` files into QGIS?

Comment: While some folders with `.adf` files are vectors, those with wNNNMMM prefixes are rasters.

Comment: @user2856 What would such a code look like using `gdalbuildvrt`? Or would you recommend using another program?

Comment: @Username Windows or MacOS/Linux?

Comment: @user2856 Arch Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Layers >> Add ***Vector*** Layer" only works with *vector* data. However, you have Arc/INFO binary GRIDs, which are rasters not vectors.

An Arc/INFO binary GRID is a directory of related files stored in a parent directory (workspace) with an INFO database directory:

[image]

GDAL can read Arc/INFO binary GRIDs either by using the GRID directory name or GRID/hdr.adf (or w001001.adf)

You can create a virtual mosaic by creating a list of all the  GRID directories (excluding the INFO directory) and using the [`gdalbuildvrt`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) command.

For absolute paths:

```
ls -d /path/to/Data-folder/be_rasters/* | grep -i -v info > gridlist.txt
```

Or to use relative paths:

```
cd /path/to/Data-folder/be_rasters
ls -d * |grep -i -v info > gridlist.txt
```

Then:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list gridlist.txt your_new_mosaic.vrt
```